# Does JavaScript execute code after a yield statement?

Tags: javascript, generator

I'm looking at some Github code and it looks like there are expressions after a yield statement.

The link is [here](https://github.com/neurosnap/gen-readlines/blob/master/index.js), and the code I'm looking at is this:

```
if (curbyte === LF && lastbyte !== CR || curbyte === CR && curpos < bytesRead - 1) {
    yield _concat(lineBuffer, readChunk.slice(startpos, curpos));

    lineBuffer = undefined;
    startpos = curpos + 1;

    if (curbyte === CR && readChunk[curpos + 1] === LF) {
        startpos++;
        curpos++;
    }
} else if (curbyte === CR && curpos >= bytesRead - 1) {
    lastbyte = curbyte;
}
```

I would have thought that everything after the line:

```
yield _concat(lineBuffer, readChunk.slice(startpos, curpos));
```

and within the same `if` block would never be reached. Is that incorrect of me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does JavaScript execute code after a yield statement?

Yes, but not right away. When generator yields, it is paused, until iterator calls `next()` on it. Then the generator resumes the execution, until it yields again.

This is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators